# Inferring mapped props when using TypeScript and React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I found a way to get type safety when using `mapStateToProps` from `react-redux`: as [documented](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-react-redux) you can define an interface and parameterize `React.Component<T>` with your interface.

However, when I am defining `mapStateToProps`, I'm already defining a function where the types of the properties of the resulting object can be inferred.  Eg,

```
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter
    };
}
```

Here, the prop `counter` can be inferred to be the same type as `state.counter`.  But I still have to have boilerplate code like the following:

```
interface AppProps {
    counter: number;
}


class App extends React.Component<AppProps> { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

So the question is, is there any way to structure the code so that I can avoid writing the type of `counter` twice?  Or to avoid parameterizing the type of `React.Component` -- even if I could have the props of the component inferred from an explicitly-hinted result type of the `mapStateToProps` function, that would be preferable.  I am wondering if the duplication above is indeed the normal way to write typed components using React-Redux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  There's a neat technique for inferring the type of the combined props that `connect` will pass to your component based on `mapState` and `mapDispatch`.

There is a new `ConnectedProps<T>` type that is available in `@types/react-redux@7.1.2`.  You can use it like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: MyState) {
    return {
        counter: state.counter
    };
}

const mapDispatch = {increment};

// Do the first half of the `connect()` call separately, 
// before declaring the component
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

// Extract "the type of the props passed down by connect"
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
// should be: {counter: number, increment: () => {type: "INCREMENT"}}, etc

// define combined props
type MyComponentProps = PropsFromRedux & PropsFromParent;

// Declare the component with the right props type
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps> {}

// Finish the connect call
export default connector(MyComponent)
```

Note that this correctly infers the type of thunk action creators included in `mapDispatch` if it's an object, whereas `typeof mapDispatch` does not.

We will add this to the official React-Redux docs as a recommended approach soon.

More details:

- [Gist: ConnectedProps - the missing TS helper for Redux](https://gist.github.com/christianchown/05e084c78ec216070a5a2b80f0534d4b)
- [Practical TypeScript with React+Redux](https://dev.to/voronar/practical-typescript-react--redux-4enh)
- [DefinitelyTyped #31227: Connected component inference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31227)
- [DefinitelyTyped PR #37300: Add ConnectedProps type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/37300)

Comment: This is great! This in combination with slices really makes redux lot easier to work with

Comment: I get complaints of the type circularly referencing itself

Comment: @Emobe : a comment saying "it doesn't work" without an actual link to the project isn't something we can help with :) That said, today we would specifically recommend using the React-Redux hooks API instead of `connect`. Please see the instructions in our docs at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start .

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. You could make your setup more concise by using Redux hooks: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

```
    // Your function component . You don't need to connect it
    const App: React.FC = () => {
      const counter = useSelector<number>((state: MyState) => state.counter);
      const dispatch = useDispatch(); // for dispatching actions
    };
```

Edit: You can if you just use the same `MyState` type. But I don't think you would want that.

Answer (score 3):

I would type mapped dispatch props, and component props separately and then combine the inferred type of the mapped state to props function. See below for a quick example. There might be a more elegant solution but hopefully, it will hopefully get you on the right track.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Action } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Lives in some lib file
type AppState = {
  counter: number;
};

type MappedState = {
  computedValue: number;
};
type MappedDispatch = {
  doSomethingCool: () => Action;
};
type ComponentProps = {
  someProp: string;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  computedValue: state.counter
});

const mapDispatchToProps: MappedDispatch = {
  doSomethingCool: () => {
    return {
      type: "DO_SOMETHING_COOL"
    };
  }
};

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  MappedDispatch &
  ComponentProps;

class DumbComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.someProp}</h1>
        <div>{this.props.computedValue}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.doSomethingCool()}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const SmartComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DumbComponent);

export default SmartComponent;
```