# Can I reduce the typescript boilerplate duplication in my redux code?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

So I have an action file defining the following:

```
export const LogInUser = (user:User, token:string) => ({
  type: UserActions.LoginUser, payload: {
    user: user, token: token
  }
})
```

Awesome.

In order to connect it, I write a mapDispatchToProps method:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any)=>({
  loginUser: (user:User, token:string)=>{dispatch(LogInUser(user, token))}
})
```

So now I'm basically duplicating the existing method signature.  Fine, I can live with that.  It's actually a halfway good idea -- what if my action's method signature differs from what I want to expose to the actual page for some reason?  Sure, that's why we do it that way.  I don't *need* that extra power, but it might be handy.

But now I have to go to my props and duplicate it *again*:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any>{
  loginUser: (user:User, token:string)=>void
}
```

At this point, I'm wondering why dispatch isn't just passed into the underlying class to begin with, instead of wrapping it in method calls.  There has to be *some* reason just about every tutorial I've seen uses this basic pattern -- though to be fair, most of them are javascript, not typescript, and don't wind up writing and re-writing the same method declaration multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's several techniques you can use to simplify all that.

First, we recommend that you use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), instead of defining it as a function:

```js
// could be shorter if the function names matched
const mapDispatch = {loginUser: LogInUser} 

// or, even just pass UserActions to connect directly
```

Second, [our new Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org) is our recommended toolset for writing simpler Redux code with good practices.  It includes [a `createSlice` function](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createSlice) that auto-generates action creators and action types automatically, so you don't have to write them by hand:

```
type UsersState = {
    user : User | null,
    token: string | null;
}

const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState: {user: null, token: null} as UsersState,
    reducers {
        loginUser(state, action: PayloadAction<{user: User, token: string>}) {
            return action.payload;
        }
    }
})

// usersSlice.actions.loginUser was automatically generated
```

You have TS automatically infer the types passed from `connect` to your own component using the `ConnectedProps<T>` approach I described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630099/62937 .

And finally, [our new React-Redux hooks API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) is generally easier to statically type than `connect`, including removing the need to define `mapDispatch` at all.

And per your other question, [`dispatch` is passed in to a connected component if you don't provide `mapDispatch` as an argument](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-dont-i-have-this-props-dispatch-available-in-my-connected-component), but [we've always recommended using action creators to keep your components "unaware of Redux"](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).

I'd suggest reading through [the Redux Starter Kit "Advanced Tutorial" docs page](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial) to see examples of how to use RSK with TypeScript and React-Redux hooks.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer.  Going to take me a while to be able to read and digest all the links enough to be able to properly follow it, I think.  CreateSlice looks _awesome_ if I understand what it does / how it fits in -- I could remove my entire actions folder in favor of just having 'slices' defining my reducers and actions in the reducer folder.  (And that's before seeing what structure the actual tutorial suggests!)

Comment: Basically, yes.  Your hand-written `someActions.ts` and `someConstants.ts` files should go away entirely, because `createSlice()` auto-generates action creators and action types.  Effectively, you write your reducers, and you get the action stuff for free.